# Inverse function and Range of $ f(x)=| x^3+1 | $

Tags: functions

I want to find range of $ f(x)=| x^3+1 | $ . Also I want to find the inverse function of this function . I also want to know the following questions :

1. For which value of $x$ the derivative of the function is not undefined ?
2. If there is not inverse function of f(x) , what is the possible cause ?

My try : 
I have tried to express $x$ interms of $f(x)$ . But I am not succeeded .

Comment: Hint: What does the absolute value tell you about the range?

Comment: That means the range of f(x) is all positive real values ?

Comment: How can I find inverse function of (x ) ??

Comment: Zero and positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute value at least tells us that the range is non-negative.

At $x=-1$, $f(x) = 0.$  As $x \to \infty$, $f(x) \to \infty.$

So the range is $0 \leq y < \infty.$

Because $f(x)$ is not one-to-one, it does not have an inverse.  (For example, $f(0) = f(-\sqrt[3]{2}) = 1.$)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the absolute value: diving into 2 cases, depending on whether $x^3+1>0$ or $x^3+1<0$, and from here, it's very easy to find the range of f, as well as the inverse function.

Case 1: $x>=-1$, f(x) = $x^3+1$

Case 2: $x<-1$, f(x) = $-(x^3+1)$

Hint: Range f = range of $x^3+1$, where $x\ge-1$ union with range of $-(x^3+1)$ where $x\le -1$.
The inverse of f is also not very hard to find, but it's not unique in some interrvals, for example, when $f(x) = 1/2$, there are 2 values of x satisfying. Look at the graph of $f(x)$ here:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+abs%28x%5E3%2B1%29+from+-2+to+2